# Как вывести поле acf для комментариев?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.

Создал 2 поля для формы комментариев.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их вывести? Пробую

```
<?php the_field('advantages', $comment); ?>
<?php the_field('advantages', $post->ID); ?>
```

Не выводится.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php the_field('advantages', "comment_".$comment->comment_ID); ?>
```

или

```
<?php the_field('advantages', $comment); ?>
```

$comment - объект комментария